# Storing password in multiple entities - Django

Tags: python, django, hash, passwords

I'm working on Django project and I want to have two different entities in database - (default Django) User and Doctors. I want to have stored password in both entities.

```
def post(self, request, pk):

    username = Doctor.objects.get(pk=a).email
    password = Doctor.objects.get(pk=a).password
    user = User.objects.create_user(username, username,  password)
    user.save()

    return redirect('ps:index')
```

Atribute in forms.py for DoctorForm:

```
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

But this is not working for passwords. I assume that the reason is hashing and salt. How to solve it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password stored in database is hashed. If you want to save a new password, use `user.set_password(new_password)` and `user.save()`. Then copy the `user.password` to another entity.